Is there a way to declare a nullable property, so that the compiler knows that the value returned by its getter is always non-null?
Consider the following example Owner class:
public sealed class Owner
{
    public required Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string? DisplayName { get; init; }
    public string? GivenName { get; init; }
    public string? Surname { get; init; }
    public required string UserPrincipalName { get; init; }
    public string? Email
    {
        get
        {
            return field ?? UserPrincipalName;
        }
        init;
    }
    public bool AccountEnabled { get; init; }

    public string GetEmail() => Email ?? UserPrincipalName;
}

The instances of this class are initialized by values returned by the Microsoft Graph API.
If the returned Email is null, then I should use the UserPrincipalName for sending emails.
I would like to get rid of the GetEmail() function and instead rely on the Email property for obtaining the owner's email. However, as the expression field ?? UserPrincipalName is always non-null, I would like to inform the compiler of it, so I don't have to handle the nullable type (string?) everywhere Email is used.
Is there a way to inform the compiler that the init-type of Email is string?, but the get-type is string?

What stops you from: public string Email?

Why?! Why nullable property if you want to guarantee non-null return? Don't you think that the two requirements are contradicting?

@Poul Bak — “What stops you...?” No, public string Email can be null because string is itself nullable, it's a reference type. I don't see how the inquirer's requirements may make any sense. The only way to help the inquirer can be opened only if we see the motivation for such strange things.

@SergeyAKryukov Because I want to be able to assign the original email to Email, and it may be null. However, if it's null, the getter should just return the UPN. In that case I avoid the GetEmail() method

[AllowNull] is designed for such a situation - it allows a property whose getter always returns non-null, to be set to null. See also the documentation here.
In this case, you need to apply it to the field:
[field: AllowNull]
public string Email
{
    get => field ?? UserPrincipalName;
    init;
}

Simply writing [AllowNull] doesn't work here because nullability of field-backed properties are a bit more complicated. See here for more details.
